# SailsJS 0.10.5 Model.subscribe(req, records) only permitted records

Tags: node.js, sockets, model, sails.js, subscribe

I want to subscribe via socket only permitted records for logged user only assigned to him. 
Model.watch(req) publish all new records, but i want separate records by find({param: value}).

How can i do that?

Example:

Server side

```
<code>


Item.find({ request: rqst.id}) 
                        .sort('createdAt DESC')
                        .limit(10)
                        .exec(function(err, items) {
                            if (err) { res.send(err); } 
                            if (items) {
                                if (req.isSocket) {
                                    sails.log("items z id "+requestId);
                                    if (req._sails.hooks.pubsub && req.isSocket) {
                                        sails.log.info('isSocket');
                                        Item.subscribe(req, items);
                                    }
                                    res.json(items);
                                }
                            };
                        })

</code>
```

Client side

```
<code>

io.socket.get(socketUrl, function (response) { 
    console.log('get');
    console.log(response); 
});

</code>
```

I don't have any response with .subscribe() method.
Sails.JS 0.9.* was fine.

Comment: Are you seeing the "items z id" log in your console?  Have you verified that `items` actually contains `Item` records?

Comment: Yes. I solved problem with sails.sockets.* methods. Model.subscribe(req, records) doesn't work for publishCreate. Only watch(req) works but for ALL new records.